# CSS Button calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have created a button with CSS like this:

```
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
```

Now I don't know how I can execute a javascript function when this button is clicked?! onClick like for HTML buttons doesn't work here.

Can you please help me? Thank you!

EDIT: This is what I have basically:

The HTML

```
<span class="button" onClick="farmArbeiter()" style="margin-left: 25%;">Kaufe Arbeiter</span>
```

Neither onClick nor onclick do work. 
The javascript

```
function farmArbeiter() { alert("it works");}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to switch to a <button> tag

Comment: I know but these buttons look ugly and don't fit to my site.

Comment: Create some button by using <button> tag then give button class to this button. You can use onclick method now.

Comment: Use Bootstrap for styling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

attach a click event handler to it using javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("BT1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("oh snap, i was clicked...");
});
```

```html
<div class="button" id="BT1">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: Weird, on snippet it works but when I copy your code on my page it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: you need to wrap this part in a block that runs after dom loads, the snippet loads fast but your page loads slower and the button is not found by javascript when the script executes

Comment: Boy am I... I've found the mistake. My external javascript file was not linked correctly. Now it works. Phew, thank you anyway! :D

Answer (score 2):

there are several ways using jquery..

```
$(document).on('click','.button',function(e){ //your code  });


$('.button').on('click',function(e){ //your code  });


$('.button')[0].onclick = MyFunction;

function Myfunction()
{
  //your code...
}
```

with javascript you can:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].onclick = function(event){ 
  //your code 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

You can use jquery.

```
$('.button').click(function(){ -- code --});
```